# If $x = \frac{y}{y+z}$ why does $\frac{z}{y} = \frac{1-x}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x = \frac{y}{y+z}$ why does $\frac{z}{y} = \frac{1-x}{x}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
   x & = \frac{y}{y+z}  &&\text{multiply both sides by $y+z$} \\[5pt]
   x(y+z) & = y         &&\text{expand the LHS} \\[8pt]
   xy+xz & = y         &&\text{group terms in $y$ (RHS)} \\[8pt]
   xz & = y-xy          &&\text{factor out $y$} \\[8pt]
   xz & = y(1-x)        &&\text{divide by $xy$ to solve for $\tfrac{z}{y}$} \\[8pt]
   \frac{z}{y} & 
= \frac{1-x}{x}         &&
\end{align}$$

Comment: Using line breaks in your answer will make it easier to read.

Comment: You're right, but that takes a bit longer to format in $\LaTeX$ :-).

Comment: Is it really that you're dividing by $xy$ rather than just $y$ in the last step?

Comment: Yes, of course! Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{1-x}{x}=\dfrac{1-\frac{y}{y+z}}{\frac{y}{y+z}}=\dfrac{(y+z)\left(1-\frac{y}{y+z}\right)}{(y+z)\cdot\frac{y}{y+z}}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the numerator and denominator of the right side by $1/y$. You obtain
$$x = \frac{y\frac{1}{y}}{(y+z)\frac{1}{y}} = \frac{1}{1+z/y}$$
Then solving for $z/y$, you get the answer.